# gdata python: store OAuth2Token

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am writing an app that is supposed to work with Google contacts.
So at some point I do the authentication with OAuth2:

```py
token = OAuth2Token(client_id=client_info["client_id"],
                    client_secret=client_info["client_secret"],
                    scope=CLIENT_SCOPE,
                    user_agent=USER_AGENT)

# I open a webserver and browser until I retrieve the 
# Auth code in a variable named "code"

token.get_access_token(code)
```

As of now, this flow starts every time the app accesses contatcs.
How do i make my application remember the authentication?

Does it have to do with refresh tokens, and if so, how does that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should save the refresh token (depending on your system configuration) that is exchanged using the code..
Next time the script runs, it should look for the refresh token first and should try to use it. If it doesn't find it or the refresh token doesn't work, it should try to get the new code.

Comment: I now found a way to (de-)serializing the OAuth2Token object with the gdata methods TokenToBlob (TokenFromBlob). So far all seemed to work for over a day - am I correct to assume, that the refresh token is magically automatically stored that way?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the TokenToBlob or TokenFromBlob methods. I'm assuming you are storing the blob and thus can extract the token when you need it when the script runs the next time. You would know when you don't need to authenticate every time the script runs.

Comment: Apparently I do not. I assume, that the refresh token ist saved with the blob then... thank you.